# Switch between synchronized and asynchronous mode with some condition

Tags: java, multithreading, asynchronous

In my case, the certain method may run under synchronized and asynchronous mode base on a condition.

What I do is use a [reentrantlock](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html) to do the switch. The code looks like below.

```
private Lock modeLock = new ReentrantLock(true);
public void specialMethod(boolean condition)}
    Callable<Result> c = () -> {
        if(condition)
            modeLock.lock();
        else{
            try {
                modeLock.tryLock(1, TimeUnit.DAYS);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            } finally {
                modeLock.unlock();
            }
        //do something here
        if(condition)
            modeLock.unlock();
        return result;
    };
    pool.submit(c);
}
```

It works for me but seems very stupid. I think I can improve it by Condition from the ReentrantLock but I don't have any clue. Could any one tell me how to improve it? Thx

Comment: So you're saying that sometimes it's thread-safe and sometimes not? That sounds odd.

Comment: @Kayaman Yes. It is strong but occur in our real case. Some special action may affect the process result for all case. We need to handle this kind of request.

Comment: If this were my codebase, I'd try to fix the actual problem. This looks like it's just fixing the symptoms. Code that is "half threadsafe" seems like a deeper design problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can perhaps use the `synchronizedCollection(Collection<T> c)` method from Java `Collections` as a pattern for what you are trying to do.

Define an interface for your class and achieve the synchronizaton by putting a wrapper around it that does the lock/unlock logic but delegates the business logic to your original unsynchronized class. Your wrapper would implement the interface (i.e., implement `specialMethod`) but would do and lock and unlock and then call the original class to do the actual logic.

Instead of passing the flag to the method, use the flag when you construct the object of the class to decide what type of class to contruct, the original one or the original plus a synchronization wrapper.

Alternatively (a slightly simpler approach), create an extension of your class (e.g. `SynchronizedClassName extends ClassName`) and override `specialMethod`. Do the locking there (unconditionally) and then call the logic in the superclass.

Again, decide which object to construct to switch between synchronized or unsynchronized.

If your synchronized wrapper exposes the unsychronized class it contains, you could access that if you wanted to switch between synchronized and unsynchronized access.

Example:

```
interface SpecialInterface {
    void specialMethod();
}

// Original class
class SpecialClass implements SpecialInterface {
    public void specialMethod() {
        ... // logic with no locking
}

class SynchronizedSpecialClass implements SpecialInterface {
    private SpecialClass logic;
    private Lock modeLock = new ReentrantLock(true);

    public SynchronizedSpecialClass(SpecialClass logic) {
        this.logic = logic;
    }

    public void specialMethod() {
        try {
            modeLock.lock();
            logic.specialMethod();
        } finally {
            modelock.unlock();
        }
    }
}

// use
SpecialInterface o = new SpecialClass();
if (lockingRequired) o = new SynchronizedSpecialClass(o);
```